# Convergence sequence in metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I am  trying to prove that: Let $(M,d)$ an metric space and $(x_n)$,$(y_n)$ sequences in $M$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $(x_n)$ converge to $L$ then $(y_n)$ converges and $\lim{y_n} = L$.

My attempt: If $\lim{y_n} = L_y$ different of $L$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0, y_n \in B_{\epsilon}(L_y)$. But $d(x_n,y_n) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ say that $y_n \in B_{\epsilon}(x_n)$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. If we take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ at the begin then $y_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(L_y)$ [...]

I know that statement is very intuitive but from here i don't know how to conclude $L_y = L$. Some one could help me?

Comment: I like your idea! Although perhaps a more straight forward option is to apply the triangle inequality-- $d(y_n,L) \le d(y_n,x_n) + d(x_n,L)$. See what you can do from there about making the right hand side small for large $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would, at most, prove that **if** the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges, **then** its limit must be $L$. But it does not prove that the sequence must converge.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $N_1\in\Bbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N_1\implies d(x_n,L)<\frac\varepsilon2$$and take $N_2\in\Bbb N$ such that $\dfrac1{N_2}<\dfrac\varepsilon2$. If $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then$$d(y_n,L)\leqslant d(y_n,x_n)+d(x_n,L)<\frac 1n+\frac\varepsilon2<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2=\varepsilon.$$

Comment: the hypothesis that $d (x, y) < \frac{1}{n} $ does not say that $\lim (y_n)$ exists? Because if don't exists the limit then $y_n$ is a irregular or tends to infinity. Can we have  $d (x_n, y_n) < \frac{1}{n}$ in these cases?

Comment: What is an irregular sequence in a metric space? What does “tends to infinity” mean in a metrix space?

Comment: Sorry I think I'm confusing the definitions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Our goal is the following: given an $\epsilon > 0$, prove that there exists an $N$ such that $y_n \in B_{\epsilon}(L)$ whenever $n \geq N$.

The fact that $x_n \to L$ means that for any new constant $\epsilon_1>0$, there is an $N_1$ such that $x_n \in B_{\epsilon_1}(L)$. The fact that $d(x_n, y_n) \leq 1/n$ means that for any new constant $\epsilon_2>0$, there exists an $N_2$ such that $d(x_n,y_n) < \epsilon_2$ (more specifically, we can take any integer $N_2 > 1/\epsilon_2$).

With that in mind, what $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ can we select (in terms of $\epsilon$) that will ensure $y_n \in B_\epsilon(L)$ for some $n$? How big does $n$ need to be for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_{n}\to x$, let $\varepsilon >0$ there exist $N_{1}\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$, such that fot any $n>N_{1}$, $d(x_{n},l)<\varepsilon$.
Then $d(y_{n},l)\leq d(y_{n},x_{n})+d(x_{n},l)<\frac{1}{n}+\varepsilon<2\varepsilon$, if $N_{3}=\max\lbrace N,N_{1}\rbrace$